# ArrayHelper with labels for specific data from query

Tags: arrays, yii2, helper, active-form

I have the following code for a dropdown:

```
<?=
    $form->field($model, 'type')
    ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->select('*')
    ->distinct()->all(), 'type', 'type'))
?>
```

Everything works the way I want it to work. Now the database values are coming out a different way then how I want them to. I want to be able to change the type value to something I choose, e.g.:

```
'computer' -> 'Laptop'
'projector' -> 'Beamer'
...
```

Is there a way to get this done in `yii2`?

Comment: Can u please explain more? You have data from DB, you are binding it to dropDown lsit with 'value of the filed, 'name of the field'. Now after istert this into a DB u want to throw it out and Change it value to like value123?

Comment: Show your ``Category`` model please

Answer (score 0):

Just do a

```
<?=
    $form->field($model, 'type')
    ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->select('*')
    ->distinct()->all(), 'id', 'type'))
?>
```

OR

```
<?=
    $form->field($model, 'type')
    ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->select('*')
    ->distinct()->all(), 'type', 'name'))
?>
```

You can choose what the key and what the values of the array are.